# Equality of morphisms in star-autonomous categories

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, natural-transformations

**1.Context**
Let $(C, \otimes,  I, a, l,r)$ be a monoidal category.
Suppose $S: C^{op} \xrightarrow{\sim} C$ is an equivalence of categories with inverse $S’$. Assume that there are bijections $\phi_{X,Y,Z}: Hom_C(X \otimes Y,SZ) \xrightarrow{\sim} Hom_C(X, S(Y \otimes Z))$ natural in $X,Y,Z$. (This makes $C$ a star-autonomous category.) Note that we do not assume that $S$ is a monoidal equivalence. For simplicity suppose that the associator $a$ is the identity and that $S$ and $S'$ are strict inverses.

**2. Question**
I am trying to verify that the following diagram commutes for all $A,B \in Obj(C)$:

$$\require{AMScd}
\require{cancel}
\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{\raise.5em\rlap{\ \ \scriptstyle #1}
   \lower.6em{\cancelto{}{\Space{2em}{1.7em}{0px}}}}}
\begin{CD}
&& S(I \otimes S'(A \otimes B))\\
& \diaguparrow{f} @VVhV \\
A\otimes S(I \otimes S'B) @>>g> A \otimes B
\end{CD}$$
where $$f:=\phi_{A \otimes S(I \otimes S'B),I,A\otimes B} \Big(id_A \otimes \phi_{S(I \otimes S'B), I, S'B}^{-1}\big( id_{S(I \otimes S'B)}\big) \Big)$$
$$g:= id_A \otimes S(l_{S‘B}^{-1})$$
$$h:=S(l_{S'(A \otimes B)}^{-1}).$$

That this diagram commutes is one step of the proof that any star-autonomous category is linearly distributive.

Using the functoriality of $S$ as well as the naturality of $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ I was able to show that it suffices to prove the following equality of morphisms in $C$:
$$\phi_{A \otimes B, I, S'(A \otimes B)} \Big( id_A \otimes \phi^{-1}_{B,I,S'B} \big(S(l_{S'B})\big)\Big)=S(l_{S'(A\otimes B)}).$$

I unsuccesfully tried using the naturality of $\phi$ and $l$. Any hints on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: it is very difficult to make the question typecheck and to get an intuition of why this equation should hold. Can you translate it into the request that a certain diagram commutes? Also, is $S$ a monoidal equivalence? A cheap observation that might be useful is that the existence of $\phi_{XYZ}$ is equivalent to the existence of a natural family of isos
$$ \psi_{XYZ} : \hom(S'(X\otimes Y),Z)\cong \hom(S'X, Y\otimes Z)$$
as a consequence of the fact that $S'\dashv S\dashv S'$.

Comment: Another potentially very confusing point is that it is not clear in what direction the left unitor goes: in order for $\phi$ to be applicable to a morphism, you have to consider *the inverse* of the left unitor $l$, which usually is taken to be $l_X : I\otimes X \to X$. No big deal, but it's a highly unwanted burden to put on anyone willing to help you!

Comment: @fosco: Thank you for your advice. I edited the question – does the edit make things clearer? Regarding your comments: The functor $S$ is not required to be monoidal. I am using the convention that $l_X: I \otimes X \rightarrow X$. Note that $S$ is contravariant. Hence, $S(l_{S'B}): B \rightarrow S(I \otimes S'B)$. I am pretty sure the formula does typecheck. Should I write the typecheck out step by step?

Comment: Way better now, thank you :-) let's see if we can find an answer...